# Neo4j Spatial database and GeoDjango framework

Tags: django, neo4j, spatial

I want to develop a web app with Neo4j Spatial database and GeoDjango framework but not fount any driver supporting spatial data. I am searching thinks that not exist??

Answer (score 0):

The Regular Neo4j drivers will all support the syntax and use requried for the Neo4j spatial library. There's no special driver requried to interact with it. Once it's installed on your Neo4j instance, you can use APOC commands to interact with it.